# HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium, python-behave

When I execute my python behave code It throws me this error.
This was working fine in my second machine(where this framework is originally designed)
But when I checkout to another machine and when I execute the behave command it throws me the below error.

```
#environment.py


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from config.config import Config


def before_scenario(context, scenario, browser_type=Config.BROWSER_TYPE):
    if not browser_type:
        context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Config.DRIVERS[0].get("path"))
        context.driver.maximize_window()
    elif browser_type.lower() == 'chrome':
        options = Options()
        # options.add_argument('--headless')
        context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager.install(self=context), chrome_options=options)
        context.driver.maximize_window()
    elif browser_type.lower() == 'firefox':
        context.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=Config.DRIVERS[1].get("path"))
        context.driver.maximize_window()
    elif browser_type.lower() == 'ie':
        context.driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=Config.DRIVERS[2].get("path"))
    elif browser_type.lower() == 'safari':
        context.driver = webdriver.Safari(executable_path=Config.DRIVERS[3].get("path"))
    else:
        raise Exception("Browser type {} is not found".format(browser_type))

    return context.driver


def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.driver.close()
    context.driver.quit()
```

Error I'm getting :

```
HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'driver'
HOOK-ERROR in after_scenario: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

The step that I am calling the driver.

```
from behave import *

from pages.loginpage import LoginPage
from config.config import Config


class LoginSteps:

    @given("I am on the Login Page")
    def i_am_on_the_login_page(context):
        context.driver.get(Config.get_environment())
        context.loginPage = LoginPage(context.driver)
```

Login Page Object

```
class LoginPage(BasePage):

    def __init__(context, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
```

Base Page

```
class BasePage:
    def __init__(context, driver):
        logging.info("Driver is initializing...")
        context.driver = driver
```

Comment: Where are you calling the before and after scenarios. Please post the remaining code as well.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida I have added the step file as well as page objects related

Comment: `LoginPage` constructor accepts two arguments `__init__(context, driver)`, whereas it's called with one argument `LoginPage(context.driver)`

Comment: You should not use hooks like functions. Try to remove params other than context, scenario from `before_scenario`. browser_type put inside and return of driver is not necessary. Reference: https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=before_scenario#environment-file-functions

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same error

Comment: I am having the same issue ,  please tell me did you find a solution for this issue ?